# Getting mp3 cover art via TagLib using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, taglib

I'm making an audioplayer for my course project in university. I'm a first-year student, so I'm not a professional programmer.

I'm using Qt 5.4 and QtCreator 3.3.1. I've included bass.dll and TagLib libraries to work with audiofiles. What am I trying to do is to get the song's cover art and pass it to QLabel (or any other widget if more convenient) on my player's GUI.
I haven't really figured out how to do it. I've been searching for examples for a while but I always end up in having errors or wrong examples. Below is the last code I've tried to use.

```
TagLib::MPEG::File file(reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(curSong->path.constData()));
TagLib::ID3v2::Tag *m_tag = file.ID3v2Tag(true);
TagLib::ID3v2::FrameList frameList = m_tag->frameList("APIC");
   if(frameList.isEmpty()) {
       return QImage();
   }

   TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame *coverImg = static_cast<TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame *>(frameList.front());

   QImage coverQImg;
   coverQImg.loadFromData((const uchar *) coverImg->picture().data(), coverImg->picture().size());

   return coverQImg;
```

This one doesn't work for me because it causes errors such as

```
C:\Qt\Projects\audioPlayer\mainwindow.cpp:553: error: undefined reference to `TagLib::List<TagLib::ID3v2::Frame*>::List(TagLib::List<TagLib::ID3v2::Frame*> const&)'
```

I suppose I've messed up with libraries, but I'm sure I've included id3v2frame.h and id3v2tag.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you even found `id3v3frame.h` (the latest version comes with `id3v2frame.h`) but `TagLib::ID3v2::FrameList` is declared in `id3v2tag.h`.

Comment: Just a misprint, fxd. Meant id3v2, of course. id3v2tag.h is also included in my project.

Comment: Is it included in `mainwindow.cpp` or `mainwindow.h`?

Comment: In `mainwindow.cpp`. However, including it in header file didn't help, because the header itself doesn't contain any of the TagLib parts.

Comment: [Errors](http://oi57.tinypic.com/7149kw.jpg) Line 553 is the one with frameList declaration

Comment: Something is wrong with your taglib header files. What taglib version do you use?

Comment: I use the latest 1.9.1 version, but the library including didn't go well, because I need to write `#include "TagLib/hpp/id3v2tag.h"` instead of just `#include "id3v2tag.h"`. Maybe something's wrong with my .pro file? [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/kubUWQE3)

Comment: Hm, I don't remember any `.../hpp/...` when building taglib. Did you build it yourself?

Comment: Oh, yes, forgot to mention this. I've copied all the .h files I needed into this folder. I thought I'd be able to use INCLUDEPATH, but it didn't work. So basically there are two copies of all .h files that I use in my project. I do realise that I did something wrong while building or linking TagLib to my project, but it worked perfectly till now (already used TagLib to extract text tags and track length).

Comment: After doing `make install` you will find taglib headers in the build directory, keep the there and use `INCLUDEPATH += C:/path/to/taglib/build/include/taglib`. And finally use angle brackets `#include <...>`.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow, thank you. Will update if don't get any results.

Answer (score 0):

You may explore a solution with `ffmpeg`.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -an -vcodec copy cover.jpg
```

- https://code.google.com/p/qtffmpegwrapper/